# Form Container input value issues

Tags: javascript, html

Radio buttons provide access and revoke access are there in HTML page. On clicking provide access it will display some options to take the values from user and this is working without ant issues, Same as on clicking revoke access button it will display some options to take the value from user. But problem here is revoke access also taking the values from provide access radio button. Any idea what is wrong in the below code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function empty() {
      var x;
      x = document.getElementById("qx").value;
      y = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
      if (x == "") {
        alert("QX number should not be null");
        return false;
      };
      if (y == "") {
        alert("Password should not be null");
        return false;
      };
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .top {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      height: 68px;
    }
    
    .top1 {
      top: 110px;
      left: 476px;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      height: 70px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayForm(c) {
      if (c.value == "1") {
        document.getElementById("provideContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("revokeContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else if (c.value == "2") {
        document.getElementById("provideContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("revokeContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {}
    }
  </script>
  <center>
    <font color="green">
      <h2>Please Select the below option</h2>
    </font><br>
    <form>
      <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input>
      <font size="3" color="orange">Provide Access</font>
      <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input>
      <font size="3" color="orange">Revoke Access</font>
    </form>
    <div class="top" style="visibility:hidden" id="provideContainer">
      <form action="C:/Users/QXJ3624/Downloads/provideaccess.sh" name="submit" METHOD="post" onsubmit="return empty()">
        <center><label for="QX"><font color="#00FFFF">Enter Qx number:</font></label>
          <input type="text" id="qx" name="qx" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" maxlength="7" title="Max 7 letters and no special characters allowed"><br><br>
          <label for="pwd"><font color="#00FFFF">Enter Password:</font></label>
          <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" minlength="8"><br><br>
          <label for="number"><font color="#00FFFF">Enter QX Number you want to delete:</font> 
     </label>
          <input type="text" id="number" name="number" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" maxlength="7"><br><br>
          <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit" onClick="return empty()">
        </center>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="top1" style="visibility:hidden" id="revokeContainer">
      <form action="cgi-bin/revokeaccess.sh" name="submit" METHOD="post" checked>
        <center><label for="QX"><font color="#00FFFF">Enter Qx number:</font></label>
          <input type="text" id="qx" name="qx" maxlength="7" title="Max 7 letters and no special characters allowed"><br><br>
          <label for="pwd"><font color="#00FFFF">Enter Password:</font></label>
          <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" minlength="8"><br><br>
          <label for="number"><font color="#00FFFF">Enter QX Number you want to delete:</font> 
     </label>
          <input type="text" id="number" name="number" maxlength="7"><br><br>
          <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit" onClick="return empty()">
          </a>
        </center>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: because your using same IDs for multiple elements , each ID should belong to a single element only

Comment: after changing the id name its workig thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the the checking with Javascript if the qx number and password is not null, its because you are assigning the inputs in revoke and provide access the same id for checking.

(id="qx" and id="pwd")

Thats what a id does. It should be only existing once on this site.